# Formulated excel to power bi

Tags: powerbi

I'm building a daily report in power bi with excel as my data source, but the extracted excel file for daily or raw data have some formula in it and power BI treat this as error, do I need to manually remove the formula and import it to power or is there a way I can only just send/import the raw file and power bi will just get the value and don't treat formula as error?

Answer (score 0):

The formula itself should not be an issue. You need to click on the Error (a clickable link as you can see below) and check why the error is being raised.

[image: Text Column formated as Date]

And once you click on it you have some more information about the error:

[image: Error Details]

Simple things like defining a column that contains a text or a special character in a number or date format raise an error. But again, the Excel formula itself **does not** raises an error.